# Is there a way to indicate the top note of a chord symbol?

Tags: chords

I'm writing a chord chart in a pseudo-lead-sheet format so I want to be concise.

I can say the bass note of my C chord should be a G by writing "C/G".

Is there a convention for saying - using letter names and symbols - the TOP note of my C chord should be a G without actually writing the note on the stave?

(I can make something up, like "C^G", but I was wondering what people have seen and if there's any accepted format.)

Comment: Writing just the top note in the staff would be a good way to at least *suggest* that players make that the top note when they voice the chord, or make it stand out. Is there a reason why you don't want to put it in the staff?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but a related question: https://music.stackexchange.com/q/38624/63781

Comment: Also not a duplicate but my answer would apply: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/130706/how-do-i-distinguish-between-chords-going-up-and-chords-going-down-when-writ

Comment: What's important to consider is that, in general, [western] music harmony uses 3 hierarchical elements: bass + other voices (creating the general harmony) and melody. The bass is *fundamental* (pun intended) to provide a harmonic reference, and while other voices (and instruments, including amount and dynamics) may affect the general color of a harmony, choosing the top voice of the harmony (which could or could not be the melody) generally doesn't change that much. In a context that doesn't indicate instrumentation, specifying that top note may be ambiguous, if not misleading - or even wrong.

Comment: I agree with Todd. Instead of a pseudo lead sheet, why not use an actual lead sheet. The notes on the stave kind of do specify the highest notes, or at least that's how full piano accompaniment is often carried out from lead sheets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no convention for specifying anything but the lowest pitch. Anything beyond that would have to be your own notation.

Comment: It's obviously the correct answer, but since the note most folk hear best is the highest, maybe there should be a conventional way to name the 'inversion'

Comment: @Tim People only hear it best if there are no other melodic lines.  In which case, isn't that top line functioning as a melody, and not simply as part of the chord?  If it's that important, perhaps it should be notated as a melody separately?

Comment: @gidds - interesting point. Whenever I've played stuff which needed the melody *and* the chords under it, those melody notes have been inevitably the highest ones in the underlying chords.

Comment: @Tim Yes, it's common to play both melody and harmony on instruments which support it (e.g. keyboard instruments, guitar, lute, etc.) — but ISTM that's often a detail of the arrangement and/or performance technique, rather than an inherent part of the piece; you could just as easily use less-melodic chord voicings and have the melody sung or played on a different instrument.

Comment: @gidds: Guitar chords with the seventh on top (e.g. G7 played 3-2-0-0-0-1) call attention to the seventh in a way that those where it is buried (e.g. E7 played 0-2-0-1-0-0) don't.  In some pieces, this distinctive sound "works", and in some other pieces it really doesn't, and someone who is sight-reading a chord sheet would have no way of knowing in advance which approach would be preferable.

Comment: @supercat this is close to the spirit of my question

Answer (score -1):

As a guitar player, I usually see these chords named alternative chords. e.g. the G with the high g (g') is called "G (alternative)".

However, that means that poeple can't distinguish between the different G chords. I think that this is usually no problem or even wanted, since these chords contain the same notes just in a slightly different order. Usually it is up to the musician how they want to play the chord.

If the composer is really picky, they can remark something like "play C with high G". Of course that is only possible if that counts for the whole song. (which is as far as I can tell usually the case)

Comment: Never come across that in 60+ yrs playing. Where might I find it?

Comment: An "alt chord" is a Dominant chord whose 5th has been altered and if it has a 9th (which is typically the case) it is altered too. G (alt) doesn't tell you the highest note in the chord.

Comment: I am indeed a guitarist, and variations of chords with different top notes are common.